# How to parse API data into google sheets

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an API response that I'm trying to place in my spreadsheet.

I managed to figure out how to call it using the following code but it all goes to the first cell. How do I make each value go to a different cell?

```js
function callCandles() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1D:tBTCUSD/hist?limit=1000&start=1577841154000&end=1606785154000&sort=-1");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

  var fact = response.getContentText();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([fact])

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to set the values in a sheet. Avoid using `for` loops with `appendRow`. It can be extremely slow for a relatively small amount of data.

Suggested solution:

```
function myFunction() {
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1D:tBTCUSD/hist?limit=1000&start=1577841154000&end=1606785154000&sort=-1");
 var fact = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,fact.length,fact[0].length).setValues(fact);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1D:tBTCUSD/hist?limit=1000&start=1577841154000&end=1606785154000&sort=-1");
 Logger.log(response.getContentText());

 var fact = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 fact.forEach(row => {
   sheet.appendRow(row);
 });
```

Hope you got some idea.